# 3D pointer seg error

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, cc

I want to stick 2D arrays in a 3D array together, first i defined the 3D array in the following way

```
int ***grid;
    grid=new int **[number];
```

then I want to assign the 2D arrays to the 3D construct

```
for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        grid[i]=rk4tillimpact2dens(...);
```

with

```
int** rk4tillimpact2dens(...
...
  static int** grid;
    grid=new int*[600];
    for(i=0;i<600;i++)
        grid[i]=new int[600];
    memset(grid,0x0,sizeof(grid));
...
  return(grid);
}
```

so far no problem, everything works fine, but when I want to access the 3D array afterwards I get a seg fault. Like that e.g.

```
printf("%d",grid[1][1][1]);
```

What is my mistake?

Best,
  Hannes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your first mistake is failing to provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `memset`?  It isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: can't I set the array with 0's through memset?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm.: I have explained that in answer.

Comment: @RomeroAzzalini one of the fundamental misunderstanding here is "*a pointer is not an array*" and "*an array is not a pointer*". An array guarantees elements that are sequential in memory. A *pointer to pointer to type* (or in your case a *pointer to pointer to pointer to type*) does not.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you for making that point clear! but in general it should make no difference, as long as you don't program some fancy time optimezed stuff?

Comment: @RomeroAzzalini Oh no -- it does. That's what the answers are saying. While you may be able to assign a pointer to the beginning of a 2D array, (that being `int (*ptr)[cols]`) you cannot take a 2D array and assign a *pointer to pointer to `int`* (e.g. `int **ptp = 2Darray;`). The first is a *pointer to an array of `[cols]` values*, the second is a *pointer to a pointer to `int`*. Think about it this way, after `ptr++;`, where would `ptr` point. After `ptp++;` what does `ptp` point to?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oh, I see. Yes, it was a bit late :D... Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Printing out the address

```
printf("%p",&grid[1][1][1]);
```

You are printing the address here. That's why you may not get what you desire to see.

```
printf("%d",grid[1][1][1]);
```

This will print the array element.

And to read an input from `stdin` you will use `scanf()` which requires you to pass address of an variable.

```
scanf("%d",&grid[1][1][1]);
```

#### Zeroing out the allocated memory

Also you can't get the size of the array using `sizeof`. SO to initialize with `0` you use `memset` on the chunks that are allocated at once with a `new`.

In your case example would be <sup>Like 1201ProgramAlarm pointed out</sup>

```
for(int i = 0; i < 600; i++){
      ...
      memset(grid[i],0,sizeof(int)*600);
}
```

There is another way you can initialise an allocated memory in c++.

`grid[i]=new int[600]();`

For example:

```
int** rk4tillimpact2dens(...
...
  static int** grid;
    grid=new int*[600];
    for(i=0;i<600;i++)
        grid[i]=new int[600]();

...
  return(grid);
}
```

Comment: The `printf` in the question has been corrected, so your first point is not longer relevant.  And your memset is wrong and will likely result in a crash.

Comment: still not working... do i have to allocate memory for  the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, it was typo in my question, I did

```
printf("%d",grid[1][1][1]);
```

it's not working :(. But even

```
printf("%d",&grid[1][1][1]);
```

or

```
printf("%d",*grid[1][1][1]);
```

would not work. The strange thing is, that there are no errors unless I try to access the array

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47342380/edit) your question instead of writing an answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you discard the very first row of each matrix with that `memset` (the actual row is leaked). While technically `grid[1][1][1]` should still be readable, it probably becomes corrupt in some other place.

Can you provide a minimal verifiable example? This is likely to solve your problem.

Comment: oh actually it generates an output, if i disscharge all memsets

Answer (score 0):

To clear out the memory allocated for `grid`, you can't do the whole NxN matrix with one memset, it isn't contiguous memory.  Since each row is allocated as a separate memory block, you need to clear them individually.

```
for(i=0;i<600;i++) {
    grid[i]=new int[600];
    memset(grid[i], 0, sizeof(int) * 600);
}
```

The `600` value should be a named constant, and not a hardcoded number.

And `grid` does not need to be a static variable.

Comment: jesus christ! it works, thank you!! why not static? isn't it local without?

Comment: I was actually back of my mind thinking that chunk of memory is allocated. But it is jagged I was missing that. That's why I missed the question.

Comment: I have added the other way. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect `memset(grid,0x0,sizeof(grid));` *not* to zero the pointer values you've just assigned to `grid[0]` through to `grid[599]`? If so, you should test that theory by inspecting the pointer values of `grid[0]` through to `grid[599]` before and after that call to `memset`, to find out what `memset` does to *true* (more on that later) arrays.

Your program is dereferencing a null pointer which results directly from that line of code. Typically, a crash can be expected when you attempt to dereference a null pointer, because null pointers don't reference any objects. This explains your observation of a crash, and your observation of the crash disappearing when you comment out that call to `memset`. You can't expect good things to happen if you try to use the value of something which isn't an object, such as `grid[1][...` where `grid[1]` is a pointer consisting entirely of zero bits.

The term *3D array* doesn't mean what you think it means, by the way. Arrays in C and C++ are considered to be a *single* allocation, where-as what your code is producing seems to be *multiple* allocations, associated in a hierarchical form; **you've allocated a *tree*** as opposed to an *array*, and `memset` isn't appropriate to *zero a tree*. Perhaps your experiments could be better guided from this point on by a book regarding algorithms, such as *Algorithms in C, parts 1-4* by *Robert Sedgewick*.

For the meantime, in C, the following will get you a *pointer to a 2D array* which you can mostly use as though it's a 3D array:

```
void *make_grid(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) {
    int (*grid)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof *grid);
    /* XXX: use `grid` as though it's a 3D array here.
     * i.e. grid[0][1][2] = 42;
     */
    return grid;
}
```

Assuming `make_grid` returns something non-null, you can use a single call to `memset` to zero the entirety of the array pointed to by that function because there's a single call to `malloc` matching that a single call to `memset`... Otherwise, if you want to zero a tree, you'll probably want to call `memset` n times for n items.

In C++, I don't think you'll find many who discourage the use of `std::vector` in place of arrays. You might want to at least *consider* that option, as well as the other options you have (such as trees; it seems like you want to use a tree, which is fine because trees have perfectly appropriate usecases that arrays aren't valid for, and you haven't given us enough context to tell which would be most appropriate for you).